# Why does optimization cause my loop to run indefinitely with an int iterator and stop condition at 2.7 billion?

Tags: c, optimization, infinite-loop

This code I was benchmarking and noticed it would not stop running when optimizations were turned on, im using Code Blocks with MinGW 4.7.0.

If I change the iterator to `unsigned i;` the loop will end with optimizations on. Otherwise I need to turn off optimizations to use the `int i;` declaration.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int a, b;
    a = 5; b = 24;
    for(i = 0; i < 2700000000; i++)
        asm_swap(&a, &b);
    return 0;
}
```

There is also a `warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90 [enabled by default]` apparently referring to the 2.7 billion constant. I do not think this would change anything as either `int` or `unsigned` can carry this value, which is part of why I am so confused here. I have no explanation.

What is the issue with having the `int` type and optimizations enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your platform, `int` is 32 bits wide.

The largest signed 32-bit integer is 2,147,483,647. The largest unsigned 32-bit integer is  4,294,967,295.

Thus 2,700,000,000 would fit in an `unsigned int`, but would not fit in an `int`.

This means that when you use `unsigned int`, your program is well-defined. However, when you use `int`, the behaviour of your program is [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: So I guess, why does it even stop in the first place with optimizations off?

Comment: @Leonardo perhaps you got lucky with optimizations turned off and it stopped, but its still UB.

Comment: @Leonardo - gcc performs extra optimisations with the assumption that there's no integer overflow, which it doesn't do by default

Comment: I will just take the compiler's pity and not worry about it then, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your platform is 32-bit your `int` will overflow and you will end up in *undefined behavior* land where anything might happen, including going on forever.